# Beginner google app maker calendar sample

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-app-maker

I'm really a beginner with Appmaker.
How can I get events from a specific calendar instead of the default calendar?

I've try several thing but I need little help.

I've try to call CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(""); instead of CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()

But I'm stuck

Any hints?

```
 /**
 * Gets Calendar events.
 * @param {Query} query - data query with parameters.
 * @return {Array<Event>} events from Calendar.
 */
function getEvents_(query) {
  var startDate = query.parameters.StartDate;
  startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  var endDate = query.parameters.EndDate;
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
  endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()) {
    return [];
  }

  var results = [];
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(startDate,endDate);




  events.forEach(function(item) {
var event = app.models.Events.newRecord();
event.StartDate = item.getStartTime();
event.EndDate = item.getEndTime();
event.Title = item.getTitle();
event.Color = item.getColor();
results.push(event);
  });

return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [Advanced Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) for it. You can plug it in in App Maker settings:
[image: Advanced Service]

Once you turn it on try this script:

```javascript
var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
  timeMin: startDate.toISOString(),
  timeMax: endDate.toISOStrng(),
  singleEvents: true,
  orderBy: 'startTime',
  maxResults: 10
});
```

You can find more info about `list` method parameters in this docs:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint!

The Calendar API Service was not added.

Work great now with:

```
var id = 'mycalendarID@group.calendar.google.com';
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id).getEvents(startDate, endDate);
```